# Keras, different precision and recall on shuffled and not-shuffled test data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm writing a model, with keras for binary classification based on some values, in my test/train set I had positive and negative examples separated, for training I shuffle them together. On test set I expect that I do not need to shuffle the data, since there should be no difference in order. While precision of the model without shuffled test data does decrease, the recall and precision stays low. On the other hand when I do shuffle the test data, precision stays the same, but the recall and precision has higher values. I left graphs of precision and recall bellow, so check them.

So first question I have is, why is there a difference between shuffled and un-shuffled data in precision and recall values?

Second question which score should I trust, or should I measure recall and precision differently?

Code bellow:

```
top = 34000
toptop=35000

x_neg = full_x_neg[:43000]
y_neg = np.zeros(len(x_neg))
x_pos = full_x_pos[:34000]
y_pos = np.ones(len(x_pos))

x_test = np.asarray(full_x_neg[43000:45000] + full_x_pos[top:toptop])
y_test = np.asarray(np.concatenate((np.zeros(len(full_x_neg[43000:45000])), np.ones(len(full_x_pos[top:toptop])))))
x_test = x_test.reshape((len(x_test), 10, 12))
x_test, y_test = unison_shuffled_copies(x_test, y_test) #shuffling test

x, y = unison_shuffled_copies(x, y)
x = x.reshape((len(x), 10, 12))
batch_size = 64
print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2,input_shape=(10, 12)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=[precision, recall, fscore])
print('Training...')
history = model.fit(x, y,validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
      batch_size=batch_size,
      epochs=15)
score, prec, rec, fscore = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size)
```

recall function:

```
def recall(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    return recall
```

precision function:

```
def precision(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision
```

[Recall with shuffled test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbFej.png)

[Precision with shuffled test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKihi.png)

[Recall withoud suffling test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yy7w.png)

[Precision without suffilng test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQWnF.png)

Comment: Shuffling of test data should not affect precision / recall. Is your code *without* shuffling just the same without the line `x_test, y_test = unison_shuffled_copies(x_test, y_test) #shuffling test` ?

Comment: @rachelim Yes it is